# How to correctly plot this set of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a data set consisting of measures of the gamma ray spectra from a single source taken at different times. I plot the data in Python and it looks like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fSd.png)

My **question** is **How to correctly plot this data in Python so it looks more presentable?** I mean if it is possible to "separate" the graphics more to be able to distinguish them better. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: There's no definitive presentation for data - it just depends on what you want to emphasize. A common thing to do is just add an offset to the curves, say, add 0 to the 1st, 4000 to the 2nd, 8000 to the 3rd, and so on. Personally, though, I like the figure as is, because although it looks a bit messy, it's easy to compare the curves, yet all the curves are distinguishable. For example, if they weren't on top of each other, it would be hard to answer a question like, "Does the curve with the largest first peak have the largest second peak?"